# Как получить доступ к элементу массива свойств?

Tags: c#, properties

Есть код:

```
public static readonly string[] DEFAULT_BUTTON = {
   "b1"
   "b2"
};
static string[] currentButton = {
    "",
    ""
};
//=====================================================================
//                    BUTTONS
//=====================================================================
public static string[] CURRENT_G_BUTTON {
    get {
        // <  i?  >
        if (currentButton[i].Equals(string.Empty) )
            currentButton[i] = Get_GButton_State(i);
            return currentButton[i];
    }
    set { currentButton[i] = value; }
}

static void Main(){
     string s = CURRENT_G_BUTTON[1];
}
```

Нужно в свойстве провести работу с элементом currentButton[i]. В данном случае с первым.
Как можно узнать индекс элемента (i) внутри свойства?

Comment: Ничего не понял, почему свойство возвращает массив? Почему этот C# выглядит как C++? Что должно делать свойство? Что такое `strint`? Почему `main()` с маленькой буквы и не `static`? А так вам наверное цикл нужен типа `for (int i = 0; i < currentButton.Length; i++)`.

Comment: strint - опечатка
"Почему main() с маленькой буквы и не static?" - потому что я с плюсов сюда перешел :) Исправил.

Мне внутри CURRENT_G_BUTTON  нужно узнать, чо в Main в операцию "[ ]" было передано значение 1

Comment: Почему не используете обычный метод? Зачем вам это возня со свойствами?

Comment: изучаю вопрос того как можно реализовать именно таким способом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> изучаю вопрос того как можно реализовать именно таким способом

Вам наверное нужно не просто свойство а индексатор

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static readonly string[] DefaultButtons =
    {
        "b1",
        "b2"
    };
    private readonly string[] currentButtons = new string[DefaultButtons.Length];

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentButtons[i]))
                currentButtons[i] = GetGButtonState(i);
            return currentButtons[i];
        }
        set { currentButtons[i] = value; }
    }

    private string GetGButtonState(int index)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Ну и как-то так использовать

```
static void Main()
{
    var instance = new MyClass();
    string s = instance[1];
}
```

Теперь этот код больше похож на C# :)